# I dropped my Panasonic HC-V180 Camera, and now camera doesn't work?

Tags: camcorder

So I had my Panasonic HC-V180 camera ready on a tripod extended to its maximum height, and then it lost balance and tipped over. The camera is able to show its storage videos and displays things like the date, whether there is an SD card or not, and its battery, menu, etc. fine but the screen is otherwise black when in video taping mode. Then after a while, the camera suddenly shows a blurry display of the camera along with an error saying "ERROR OCCURRED. PLEASE TURN UNIT OFF, THEN TURN ON AGAIN." It won't record anything.

What is wrong with it? Perhaps the viewfinder?  I have no idea where to go take it to fix (I live in Bay Area of CA, USA)

Comment: I had the same problem. After reading your problem I had to think if I'd dropped mine. I hadn't really, just plonked it roughly on its lens end. So, I tried something. I tried dropping on the battery end from only a few centimetres in height onto a table. Bang! Voila! It works....for now.

Comment: Okay, this is ridiculous, I know. I was having the exact problems shared here... And I did Matty's "plonk" technique from, like, half an inch and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As far as what is technically wrong with your camera; the answer is it’s busted. You dropped it.

As far as repair, go to the Panasonic Website, navigate to support, cameras, repairs. Depending on your camera model, it will give you your options on repairing it.

Some companies use vendors, some charge a fee up front just to accept it to determine what needs to be repaired, then quote a price for parts and labor.

But the answer to where to get it fixed is on the Panasonic website. Youll have to mail it to a service center. Then decide if its worth repairing.